# Обмен между сайтом и 1С составом заказа

Tags: битрикс, 1с

Как проверить обмен составом заказа между сайтом и 1С. Не всегда изменения в заказе при его сохранении прогружаются в 1С и так же в обратную сторону, мы не всегда получаем изменения в заказе, которые делают в 1С;

Подскажите пожалуйста приблизительные шаги, для решения этой проблемы, на стороне 1С-Bitrix, что я могу сделать?
Пока что я пробовал смотреть так.
На втором шаге заказы из bitrix в 1С показал:
failure Ошибка проверки источника запроса. Обновите модуль обмена.

Заказы из Битрикс в 1С

1.https://<адрес_сайта>/bitrix/admin/1c_exchange.php?type=sale&mode=checkauth

2.https://<адрес_сайта>/bitrix/admin/1c_exchange.php?type=sale&mode=init&sessid=
<id_сессии_из_первого_запроса>

3.https://<адрес_сайта>/bitrix/admin/1c_exchange.php?type=sale&mode=query&sessid=<id_сессии_из_первого_запроса>

4.https://<адрес_сайта>/bitrix/admin/1c_exchange.php?type=sale&mode=success&sessid=<id_сессии_из_первого_запроса>

Заказы из 1С в Битрикс

1.https://<адрес_сайта>/bitrix/admin/1c_exchange.php?type=sale&mode=checkauth

2.https://<адрес_сайта>/bitrix/admin/1c_exchange.php?type=sale&mode=init&sessid=<id_сессии_из_первого_запроса>